# i erase the administrator account now i cant make any changes on my pc

Tags: windows

i erase the administrator account on my pc and now I cant make any changes it says only the administrator the  shows the option accept an d not but the option accept you cant click on it

Comment: what operating system are you using? if its XP, you can prob fix this in a few easy steps

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible to delete the last admin account on any OS. So check whether your computer has another use which is admin. Then login as that admin and restore whatever you need to restore.

Comment: i think hes talking about his MAIN account, not the actual administrator account.